# YouTube video in an iframe in Webview continues to play after navigation

Tags: windows-8

I had to embed a YouTube video in one of my windows 8 xaml apps. I added an iframe in a webView like [this](http://silverspoted.blogspot.com/2012/12/to-embed-youtube-videos-in-windows-8.html).
Now my problem is that when I navigate away from the page the YouTube video continues to play. Since the page in which the WebView is not present in the current view after navigation, I am not able to access the iframe as well. Is there a way to stop the video somehow once I navigate away from the page?

Thanks and Regards,
Ramya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to pause the video (and cache the page) so they can come back to where they were?

If not, then a less than elegant (but effective) option:

> ```
>     protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
>     {
>         base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
>         wv.NavigateToString("");
>     }
> ```

If you want to pause the video, I believe you should be able to accomplish that goal by including some JavaScript in the YouTube IFrame API in combination with [OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx) and a call to [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx).